# Recursive version of an integral

Tags: integration

I don't understand how can we pass from this integral $y_n=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^n}{x+10}$ to this recursive version $y_n=\int_{0}^{1}x^{n-1}dx-10y_{n-1}$. Could anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Hint:  $\frac {x^n}{x+10}=x^{n-1}-\frac {10x^{n-1}}{x+10}$

Comment: Indeed, I hadn't seen the trick! Thank you